# GNU make linker input file unused because linking not done

Tags: makefile, linker-errors, gnu

I have some troubles with my make file. All the output files are generated, but linking is not possible. Therefore, I don't get the output executable. Where is my mistake?

Here is my recipe for the output file:

```
gcc main.o memory.o startup_msp432p401r_gcc.o system_msp432p401r.o interrupts_msp432p401r_gcc.o -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -std=c99 -DHOST -MM -Wl,-Map=c1m2.map -T msp432p401r.lds -o c1m2.out
```

And here is the whole makefile:

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),HOST)
CC = gcc
else
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
endif

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = mthumb
SPECS = nosys.specs

# Compiler Flags and Defines
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MSP432)
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -std=c99 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -march=armv7e-m -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 --specs=nosys.specs
LDFLAGS = -T msp432p401r.lds
else
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -std=c99 -DHOST
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map -T msp432p401r.lds
endif

TARGET = c1m2

CPPFLAGS =  -MM


OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)


%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@


.PHONY: build

build: all

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET).out

$(TARGET).out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).map
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean all the *object* (`.o`) files are generated?  Because the linked program (`$(TARGET).out`) is an output file, too.  If indeed the linked program is not created, then does `make` emit a diagnostic message?  What is the full command by which you ren `make`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean the object files are generated. My make command is "make all". Then i would expect an output file (c1m2.out), which isn't there. Make just tells that linking wasn't done, but it is not an error message. I don't really understand why linking didn't happen.

Comment: Fine.  Regardless of whether you consider it an error message, what is the specific message that `make` emits about linking not having been performed?

Comment: gcc: warning: main.o: linker input file unused because linking not done. This warning is shown for all the object files.

Comment: What you describe does not seem consistent with the makefile presented, because the diagnostics you call out appears to be about building the individual object files, not about the final executable, yet it does not look like the options for building the object files would include any specifying a linker script.  On the other hand, the per-object options do not include the `-c` option, so there should indeed be an attempt to link.  You could try removing the `%o: %c` rule altogether, for as far as I can tell, the built-in one would serve your needs.

Comment: I just realized that a -c is added to the command automatically, when I run make object.o, altough I don't have that in my makefile. That explains the warning, and should not be a problem in the end. However, when I run make all no executable file appears and at the same time it gives no error or warning. In the receip for the output file there is no -c. I miss the files c1m2.out and c1m2.map. Why aren't they in the folder? All the object files appear.

Comment: No, that strongly suggests that the makefile you have presented is not the one actually being used.  `make` does not differentiate between file types or add options you have not specified, except to the limited extent that its built-in rules have those effects.  Its built-ins do not apply where any explicit rule in the makefile does, so that does not provide for extra options being added in the case you describe.

Comment: After I included the header files from other directories it now works. Before that I just had them in the same folder as the source files and the makefile. So it seems there was a problem in connection with the includes. In general, is it a problem for make to have the header files in the same folder as the source files? I mean, usually the headers are in different folders, but that should not be a problem per se. Or is it? Thank your for your effort and your help.

Comment: Headers have already served their purpose by the time the linking stage is reached.  If there were a problem with locating headers -- and there might have been -- then I would expect diagnostics about that to have been emitted too.  Header location does matter, in that the compiler needs to be able to find the files, but there is no general rule about whether they should be in the same folder with the other sources.  That arrangement is pretty common, especially for smaller projects.  The form of the `#include` directives and the compile options matter here.